# Copy frameworks without Carthage

Tags: ios, carthage

I'm faced with requirement to have project working on machine without Carthage binaries installed. As I understand the only problem is `copy-framework` phase because it use `carthage` binary. Could you please guide me how to do this step just with Xcode tools?

Comment: I am also interested to know